# Parse a string with an given object in angular2

Tags: angular

I want to create a translate service (ng2-translate does not fit my needs). And I have a problem.

It's easy to solve in angular 1.x: `$interpolate(translation)(interpolationParams)`.

Ok there is no interpolate. I don't understand why. But no problem. Find {{.*?}} and parse the inner could work to (smth like: `translation.replace(/{{(.*?)}}/g, function(substr, expr) { return $parse(expr)(interploationParams); })`. But there is also no $parse.

DynamicComponentLoader seems to be heavy overloaded for this. And it will be difficult for a pipe...

There have to exist functions that do exactly this. It has to be done by angular2 too.

a short example what I'm trying to do:

```
@Injectable()
export class Translator {
  private _http: Http;
  private _translations: any = {};

  constructor(@Inject(Http) http: Http) {
    this._http = http;
  }

  private _load(lang) {
    this._http(lang+'.json')
      .map(res => res.JSON)
      .subscribe(
        (translations) => this._translations[lang] = translations
      );
  }

  public translate(key, params) {
    var translation = this._translations[lang][key];
    translation = $interpolate(translation)(params); // not working
    return translation;
  }
}
```

Comment: If you are using Typescript take a look at Typescript's [template string](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/template-strings.html) interpolation... `console.log(\`1 and 1 make ${1 + 1}\`);`

Comment: thanks looks interesting - does it work at runtime?

Comment: It's compiled to js at build-time, here's an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/Gl1ufIYhnL4hSf73DU8Y?p=preview

Comment: yes but the translation comes dynamically from json files

Comment: It shouldn't matter where the value is coming from. Do you have any code to see what you're trying to do? This is all hypothetical without it (;

Comment: my actual solution is something like this, but it is very dirty: `function _p(exp, params) { return eval('with(params) { (' + expression + ') }'); }`